# How can I match using regex integer before string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like "`1 first - 22 second - 7 third`", and I need to get the integer value for each item. For example, if I want get the third value they will return `7`.

I tried with this code but it doesn't work:

```
item = detail.scan(/( - )\d( second.*)/)
```

Comment: Do you mean the third number each time? Any integer in the string?

Answer (score 1):

`scan` is great for some data, but if you want to make sure you don't just collect garbage data you probably need something a little more structured for this. A quick split on the record separator " - " ensures each item is separated from the others before extracting the integers from the item.

```
your_string = "1 first - 22 second - 7 third"
items = your_string.split ' - '
numbers = items.map { |item| item[/\d+/].to_i }

#=> [1, 22, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"1 first - 22 second - 7 third".split(" - ").map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the right regex:

```
str = "1 first - 22 second - 7 third"

str.scan(/\d+/).map{ |i| i.to_i } # => [1, 22, 7]
```

If you need access to a particular value use an index into the returned values:

```
str.scan(/\d+/).map{ |i| i.to_i }[-1] # => 7
str.scan(/\d+/).map{ |i| i.to_i }[2] # => 7
str.scan(/\d+/).map{ |i| i.to_i }.last # => 7
```